# Making pairs of rows from SQL results without repeating values and only using SQL

Tags: sql

Due to misreading a question, I stumbled upon something that I could find no way to do.  I have a table of names:

```
Name
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I want to output those as:

```
A B
C D
E F
```

I could find no way to do this from within SQL even though it would be trivial outside of SQL.  Is this possible?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of doing this is using `row_number()`.  Let me assume either that ordering is not important or that you have some column that specifies the ordering, which I'll call `id`.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering in the table; only ordering expressed by columns.

A typical approach is:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then name end) as name2
from (select name, row_number() over (order by id) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor(seqnum / 2);
```

Note that some databases use the `mod()` function instead of `%` for calculating the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gordon's. As you can see there are multiple approaches:

```
with data as (
    select Name, row_number() over (order by Name) - 1 as seq /* start at zero */
    from T
)
select d1.Name, d2.Name
from
    data d1 left outer join data d2 on d2.seq = d1.seq + 1
where
    d1.rn % 2 = 0
```

One advantage to Gordon's approach is that you can easily change to more than two columns without involving extra joins.